# Regex currency Python 3.5

Tags: regex, python-3.x, currency

I am trying to reformat the Euro currency in text data.  The original format is like this: EUR 3.000.00 or also EUR 33.540.000.- .
I want to standardise the format to €3000.00 or €33540000.00.
I have reformatted EUR 2.500.- successfully using this code:

```
import re
format1 = "a piece of text with currency EUR 2.500.- and some other information"
regexObj = re.compile(r'EUR\s*\d{1,3}[.](\d{3}[.]-)')
text1 = regexObj.sub(lambda m:"\u20ac"+"{:0.2f}".format(float(re.compile('\d+(.\d+)?(\.\d+)?').search(m.group().replace('.','')).group())),format1)
Out: "a piece of text with currency €2500.00 and some other information"
```

This gives me €2500.00 which is correct. I've tried applying the same logic to the other formats to no avail.

```
format2 = "another piece of text EUR 3.000.00 and EUR 5.000.00. New sentence"
regexObj = re.compile('\d{1,3}[.](\d{3}[.])(\d{2})?')
text2 = regexObj.sub(lambda m:"\u20ac"+"{:0.2f}".format(float(re.compile('\d+(.\d+)?(\.\d+)?').search(m.group().replace('.','')).group())),format2)
Out: "another piece of text EUR €300000.00 and EUR €500000.00. New sentence"
```

and

```
format3 = "another piece of text EUR 33.540.000.- and more text"
regexObj = regexObj = re.compile(r'EUR\s*\d{1,3}[.](\d{3}[.])(\d{3}[.])(\d{3}[.]-)')
text3 = regexObj.sub(lambda m:"\u20ac"+"{:0.2f}".format(float(re.compile('\d+(.\d+)?(.\d+)?').search(m.group().replace('.','')).group())),format3)
Out: "another piece of text EUR 33.540.000.- and more text"
```

I think the problem might be with the regexObj.sub(), as the .format() part of it is confusing me. I've tried to change re.compile('\d+(.\d+)?(.\d+)?') within that, but I can't seem to  generate the result I want. Any ideas much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have control over the text? It seems strange that the decimal and thousand separator is using the same character - a `dot`.

Comment: You mean like this: [`\d[.\d]*\d(?:\.-)?`](https://regex101.com/r/4wx3tC/1/) ?

Comment: @Borisu, no I don't have control over the text. It's from a third party, and these formats are one of many for Euros alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the regex. My propositions is:

```
EUR\s*(?:(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)\.-|(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)(\.\d{2}))
```

Details:

- `EUR\s*` - The starting part.
- `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group - a container for alternatives.
- `(` - Start of a capturing group #1 (Integer part with ".-" instead of
  the decimal part).
- `\d{1,3}` - Up to 3 digits.
- `(?:\.\d{3})*` - ".ddd" part, 0 or more times.
- `)` - End of group #1.
- `\.-` - ".-" ending.
- `|` - Alternative separator.
- `(` - Start of a capturing group #2 (Integer part)
- `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*` - Like in alternative 1.
- `)` - End of group #2.
- `(\.\d{2})` - Capturing group #3 (dot and decimal part).
- `)` - End of the non-capturing group.

Instead of a lambda function I used "ordinary" replicating function,
I called it `repl`. It contains 2 parts, for group 1 and group 2 + 3.

In both variants dots from the integer part are deleted, but the "final"
dot (after the integer part) is a part of group 3, so it is not deleted.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
import re

def repl(m):
    g1 = m.group(1)
    if g1:   # Alternative 1: ".-" instead of decimal part
        res = g1.replace('.','') + '.00'
    else:    # Alternative 2: integet part (group 2) + decimal part (group 3)
        res = m.group(2).replace('.','') + m.group(3)
    return "\u20ac" + res

# Source string
src = 'xxx EUR 33.540.000.- yyyy EUR 3.000.00 zzzz EUR 5.210.15 vvvv'
# Regex
pat = re.compile(r'EUR\s*(?:(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)\.-|(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)(\.\d{2}))')
# Replace
result = pat.sub(repl, src)
```

The result is:

```
xxx €33540000.00 yyyy €3000.00 zzzz €5210.15 vvvv
```

As you can see, no need to use `float` or `format`.